# Enhance list comprehension code to avoid method call used in list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

Method `check_list_comprehension` have list comprehension which is returning the correct result, but I have called another method inside list comprehension code, I would like to have just one method which will return the same result.

```
def check_list_comprehension():
    links = [{'link': 'test.com', 'params': {}}]
    previous_url_results = [{'for_next_params': {'seckey': 'gjgJG'}}, {'for_next_params': {'seckey': 'gjfggJG'}},
                            {'for_next_params': {'seckey': 'gjgJfgggG'}}]
    links = [_operations(link, previous_url['for_next_params'])
             for link, previous_url in itertools.product(links, previous_url_results)
             if 'for_next_params' in previous_url
             ]
    print(links)


def _operations(link, y):
    link['params'] = {**link['params'], **y}
    return link

check_list_comprehension()
```

The output of this code:

```
[{'link': 'test.com', 'params': {'seckey': 'gjgJfgggG'}}, {'link': 'test.com', 'params': {'seckey': 'gjgJfgggG'}}, {'link': 'test.com', 'params': {'seckey': 'gjgJfgggG'}}]
```

Please suggest a better pythonic way to do it.

Comment: I suggest to pre-filter `itertools.product(links, previous_url_results)` to `itertools.product(links, (p for p in previous_url_results if 'for_next_params' in p)` so you're not performing a product to throw it away. Reduces complexity

Comment: BTW the secret key is always the same. You probably need to create a copy of `link`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, your result is wrong: note that you get the same secret key for all items. This is because you don't copy "enough" `links`...

Well you can fix it by adding a `copy()` to your update method, but since you want it in one line, then why not rebuilding each occurrence from scratch?

Another performance issue is that you're performing the `product` *then* you filter unwanted elements out, instead of filtering the input elements.

Here's my fix for both problems:

```
import itertools
def check_list_comprehension():
    links = [{'link': 'test.com', 'params': {}}]
    previous_url_results = [{'for_next_params': {'seckey': 'gjgJG'}}, {'for_next_params': {'seckey': 'gjfggJG'}},
                            {'for_next_params': {'seckey': 'gjgJfgggG'}}]
    links = [{'link':link['link'], 'params':previous_url['for_next_params']}
             for link, previous_url in itertools.product(links, (p for p in previous_url_results if 'for_next_params' in p))
             ]
    print(links)
```

result:

```
[{'link': 'test.com', 'params': {'seckey': 'gjgJG'}}, {'link': 'test.com', 'params': {'seckey': 'gjfggJG'}}, {'link': 'test.com', 'params': {'seckey': 'gjgJfgggG'}}]
```

If `params` isn't empty at start, this code discards the init value. That can be fixed by changing

```
{'link':link['link'], 'params':previous_url['for_next_params']}
```

to:

```
{'link':link['link'], 'params':{**link['params'], **previous_url['for_next_params']}
```

(this kind of dictionary "addition" isn't available until python 3.5 BTW, reference: [How to merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression))